# Run VBA code on slide transition - PowerPoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am trying to show a message box every time a new slide appears. Found the following code on the internet. Not sure what I need to change here? Thanks for help.

```
Sub OnSlideShowPageChange(ByVal SSW As SlideShowWindow)
    If SSW.View.CurrentShowPosition = _
        SSW.Presentation.SlideShowSettings.StartingSlide Then
        MsgBox "a message bos appears"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Capturing events is a little more complicated than writing a Sub. Here's a page on how to enable events in PowerPoint: http://www.rdpslides.com/pptfaq/FAQ00004_Make_your_VBA_code_in_PowerPoint_respond_to_events.htm

Answer (score 0):

You haven't told us what the problem is. I'd imagine it's that the message box appears only on the first slide and not on any of the others.

That's what your code's TELLING it to do, though. Try this instead:

```
Sub OnSlideShowPageChange(ByVal SSW As SlideShowWindow)
        MsgBox "a message box appears"
End Sub
```

If this doesn't work, you may need to add an ActiveX control to either the first slide or possibly to each slide; sometimes OnSlideShowPageChange won't fire unless you do this. It's a bug in PowerPoint.

John's correct in that to trap most events, you need to go to special lengths. This particular event requires nothing more than a subroutine, though.